# JQuery window.location doesn't work

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

I'm using JQuery and add event listener on checkbox button. I want to send a different request to the server, based on whether checkbox is selected or not. when I console things everything seems to be ok, but when I add window.location.assign it doesn't work properly.

Here is my piece of code:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="isPageNoSorted">

<script>
    $('#isPageNoSorted').change(function() {
        isPageNoSorted = !isPageNoSorted

        $.get('/bookShow/' + isPageNoSorted  + '/' + <%= currentPage%> ).done(function(data) {
            console.log('/bookShow/' + isPageNoSorted  + '/' + <%= currentPage%>)
            //window.location.assign('/bookShow/' + isPageNoSorted  + '/' + <%= currentPage%>)
        })
    })
</script>
```

my server code:

```
router.get('/bookShow/:isPageNoSorted/:page', (req, res) => {
    var isPageNoSorted = req.params.isPageNoSorted;
    var page = req.params.page || 1;
    var perPage = 5;
    if (isPageNoSorted == "true") {
        bookModel.find({
                isDeleted: false
            }).sort('-pageCount')
            .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
            .limit(perPage)
            .exec((err, data) => {
                if (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        bookModel.find({
                            isDeleted: false
                        }).count().exec((err, count) => {
                            res.render(
                                'main/bookShow', {
                                    books: data,
                                    pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
                                    currentPage: page,
                                    isPageNoSorted: isPageNoSorted
                                }
                            );
                        })
                    } else {
                        res.send("Not enough data! Hajiiii :))")
                    }
                } else if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
    } else {
        bookModel.find({
                isDeleted: false
            }).sort('-createdAt')
            .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
            .limit(perPage)
            .exec((err, data) => {
                if (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        bookModel.find({
                            isDeleted: false
                        }).count().exec((err, count) => {
                            res.render(
                                'main/bookShow', {
                                    books: data,
                                    pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
                                    currentPage: page,
                                    isPageNoSorted: isPageNoSorted
                                }
                            );
                        })
                    } else {
                        res.send("Not enough data! Hajiiii :))")
                    }
                } else if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
    }
});
```

after uncommenting the `window.location` console.log doesn't log anything more. The request is sent to the same URL and the page is just refreshed.

**NOTE** I have tried another way to handle this problem. The solution is as follows:

```
$('#isPageNoSorted').change(function () {
            isPageNoSorted = !isPageNoSorted
            $.get('/bookShow/' + isPageNoSorted  + '/' + <%= currentPage%> ).done(function(data) {
                $('html').html(data.replace(/<html>(.*)<\/html>/, "$1"));
            })
        })
```

but I'm facing with a new error which is:

> Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

I am really in the middle of nowhere, looking forward to see a good solution.

Comment: try window.location.href();

Comment: @dickrichie window.location.href is not a function, I used windows.location.href = ... though. It still doesn't work properly :(

Comment: Is there an actual functionality problem or you just don't see the `console.log()` because most debuggers are set by default to clear the log when you change pages.  You can configure them (I think) to retain the log when changing pages if you want to see the data.

Comment: Also, you should probably pass `window.location.assign()` a full URL with http:// or https:// on the front.

Comment: @jfriend00 the functionality works well and I have test it using postman. The problem is whenever the user click on checkbox button I wanna show him/her sorted results on the page. but the page is just refreshed with the previous data.

Comment: href without ()...sorry.

Comment: Perhaps the browser page is cached?  Also, your code doesn't really make sense.  You do `$.get()` of a URL and do nothing with the results of that Ajax call and then after you do that, you do `windows.assign()` of the exact same URL.  What is that supposed to do?  What's the point of the Ajax call?

Comment: @jfriend00 the urls are different. isPageNoSorted is a boolean sometimes is true or false. The data recieved from server is differ based on its value. The point of this ajax call is just to show the updated data.

Comment: The ajax call does NOT show ANYTHING by itself.  It just retrieves data for your Javascript.  It's up to your Javascript to do something with the data.  Does your server create a different page based on the value of `isPageNoSorted`?

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, I know. What I want , is just to receive data. I recommend you to learn [ejs](http://ejs.co/)

Comment: Your ajax call is not doing anything.  I know EJS.  I recommend you learn about ajax.    You don't show any of your server code so I would have no idea what your server is or isn't doing when it receives a different URL.  I will leave now since you appear to just want to insult me when I try to help.  Bye.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm so sorry, I didn't want to insult you my friend. I will edit the post and put my server code there.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not very fluent in English. I really didn't want to disturb you.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for assign is below:

```
location.assign("https://www.w3schools.com");
```

You need to pass the complete url. another thing is you no need to use $get request. Modify your code like below and it will work like a charm.

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="isPageNoSorted">

<script>
    $('#isPageNoSorted').change(function() {
        isPageNoSorted = !isPageNoSorted

         $.get('/bookShow/' + isPageNoSorted  + '/' + <%= currentPage%> ).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //process the data and convert to html formatand replace with old one.
    }) 
        
    })
</script>
```

Please make sure to replace http://www.example.com with your url.

Comment: I did like you say, but nothing has changed :(.

Comment: what is happening? as it will redirect to the user to the sorted url.

Comment: the page just reload and the content of console.log disappears in milliseconds.

Comment: what is the new url in reloaded page? it is changed or same?

Comment: everything is the same. when I use postman the received data is OK. I'm sure that the problem is from jquery redirect url.

Comment: It works. But what it is the best way to replace the data with the previous html file data?

Comment: I don't know your html but for example if you have a div then you can set this data to that div.